# No signature of method: java.net.URL.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [http://website.com]

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

This groovy dsl code produce java error in jenkins:

ERROR: (script, line 61) No signature of method: java.net.URL.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [http://website.com]

```
definition {
        cpsScm {
          scm {
            git {
                remote {
                    url("http://website.com")
                    credentials("${Cred_ID}")   
                }  
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins 2.295

i found setURL() method here and it works good:
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git/hudson/plugins/git/UserRemoteConfig.html

```
definition {
        cpsScm {
          scm {
            git {
                remote {
                    setUrl("http://website.com")
                    credentials("${Cred_ID}")   
                }  
            }
          }
        }
}
```